# Profile ADO.NET statements without access to SQL Server Profiler

Tags: c#, .net, sql, ado.net, profiling

Consider a block of code like this:

```
using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection("{connection string}"))
{
    c.Open();

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Table (Field1, Field2) VALUES (@Field1, @Field2)", c))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Field1", "some value");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Field2", 10);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to see the actual statement sent to the server, but the kicker is I don't have access to SQL Server Profiler via our Network/SQL administrators. Is there any way I can get at the actual statement submitted to the server?

Comment: Do you mean that you want the parameters as well? Because the command you're sending is already the entire command.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, yes. And more succinctly stated, when sent to the server you get the command and then the literal parameters values afterward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a range of tools that do exactly this. If you are in asp.net, you may find [MiniProfiler](http://miniprofiler.com/) a good start (you can use it on other platforms, but the UI tooling is stronger on asp.net). The main change involved here would be to move from SqlCommand etc to use `c.CreateCommand`, since it works by *wrapping* the connection (decorator pattern) - while it is still a DbConnection, the outermost object is not a SqlConnecion any more. I have to say, though - in this particular example you already *know* the exact command sent to the server. It is useful for finding the surprises, though. If that doesn't suit, "Hibernating Rhinos" offer a range of profiling tools, and many Orpheus general-purpose profiling tools will include ado.net tools; the main reason I mention MiniProfiler is that is is free, readily available, and very low impact (it is what we wrote to profile stackoverflow.com - and we leave it "on" 24x7)

Comment: Right on, in the example provided I knew exactly what was being sent, and the literal one wouldn't really add any value. However, this is what I was looking for. With this idea we could use a DI container to create our commands so that in `Debug` we could use the decorated command, but in `Release` we could use the optimized `SqlCommand`, and that would work really nice. **Am I right on that observation?**

Comment: @Michael exactly - as long as your DI provides a DbConnection, not a SqlConnection, then that will work great with a tool like MiniProfiler. But note that you *don't necessarily need to turn it off*; if stack exchange can leave it on 24x7, then most sites can. Most interesting performance problems only happen in production, so having it available instantly is really useful (you can obviously filter who gets to see profiling data, etc)

Comment: LOL, yeah after seeing your comment that it's left on, all the time, for stack exchange I figured we could probably leave it on! I've already downloaded it and will start merging it into our code bases I think. Gotta get through all the red tape, but once that's done, I'm in like Flynn! Marc, I never get or read an answer from you without learning something - thanks for everything friend!

Comment: @Michael if you want to try it, we leave it enabled for public users on [sede](http://data.stackexchange.com/) - since that code is all OSS there is no harm in us showing this data to the user (for their own query)

Comment: Sweet, I'm checking it out now!